# Refactoring Rails scope method CASE-WHEN-THEN-ELSE-END in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring, sql-order-by

I'm using MySQL and upgrading my application to Rails 7. In doing so, I've to refactor some order-related queries in my scope methods.

Before of Rails 7 I was using the following scope method (call it the "original scope method"):

```
scope.order(sanitize_sql_array(["CASE articles.author_id WHEN ? THEN 1 ELSE 2 END", author.id]))
```

In Rails 7 the above statement raises the error:

> ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeReference (Dangerous query method
> (method whose arguments are used as raw SQL) called with non-attribute
> argument(s): "CASE articles.author_id WHEN '3784' THEN 1 ELSE 2
> END". This method should not be called with user-provided values, such
> as request parameters or model attributes. Known-safe values can be
> passed by wrapping them in Arel.sql().):

What in Rails 7 might come in handy in these cases is the newly added method [`in_order_of`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-in_order_of). So, the original scope method might become:

```
scope.in_order_of(:author_id, [author.id])
```

However this `in_order_of` method adds to the SQL query a (*unwanted*) WHERE clause i.e. the "**AND 'articles'.'author_id'**" part in the following query:

```
SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` 
WHERE (articles.some_other_column >= 10) AND `articles`.`author_id` IN (3784) 
ORDER BY FIELD(`articles`.`author_id`, 3784) DESC
```

The (*unwanted*) effect of the additional WHERE clause is the removal from the query result of all the records that were present when I was using the original scope method before of Rails 7 i.e in the above example, author ids other than 3784 are ignored but should be present in the query result.

How can I build/refactor in Rails 7 the scope method equivalent to the original "CASE-WHEN-THEN-ELSE-END" that I was using before of Rails 7 in order to order records by the given author id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty easy to call any function with Arel:

```
scope.order(
  Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('FIELD', [arel_table[:author_id], author.id]).desc
)
```

`Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new` takes an function name and an array of arguments.

Comment: The main advantage is that you avoid the string interpolation (and the warning from brakeman).

Comment: Thanks @max, your solution works. Since I've access to the class i.e. `Article` (`self`), I would make the table name i.e. `articles` explicit this way: `order(Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('FIELD', [self.arel_table[:creator_user_id], creator_user.id]).desc)`. This avoids Ruby on Rails to infer it itself, which will save me from a lot of potential future headaches though.

Comment: Using self here isn't needed. `scope` is just syntactic sugar to write class methods and the implicit self in a class method is the class itself. This is just Ruby and Rails doesn't have to infer anything.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution by wrapping attributes (known-safe values) in Arel.sql() as advised in the error message.

```
scope.order(Arel.sql("FIELD(articles.author_id, #{author.id}) DESC"))
```

So the SQL query will be:

```
SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` 
WHERE (articles.some_other_column >= 10)
ORDER BY FIELD(`articles`.`author_id`, 3784) DESC
```